# Google Maps API v3 base map visibility

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

Is it possible to change visibility or opacity of google base map ?
I am adding it like in simple example, and adding data layer as overlay and want to see only vector markers. Is it possible?

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107068/how-to-reduce-the-opacity-of-a-google-maps-layer-in-cartodb-js). Note the question is about CartoDB, but the answer is about google-maps baselayers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add transparency to your code you would have to modify your example like this:

```
var map;
var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

function initialize() {

var options = [{
    stylers: [{lightness:90}]
 }];


 var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
   },
   mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

   var styledMapOptions = {
       name: 'Custom Style'
     };   

   var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(options, styledMapOptions);  

   map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);

   }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

In this case the basemap would take a 90% transparency (referred to in the code as *lightness*).

The following links can be very useful when styling maps: 
[Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=stackoverflow) and [an example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple).

Please let me know if the code makes sense to you, or if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a good source of styles at Snazzy Maps, a community built around creating great looking styles for Google Maps. Your might want to check it out:

https://snazzymaps.com/